# Careers ad asking if I want to work where I already work?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, jobs, advertising

I just saw this ad on the side of Stack Overflow:

[image]

I currently work for stealth.travel.

It even shows it when I click on the link!

[image]

How is it possible that the system does not link 2 + 2 together and not show me the company I already work for in the banner ad? (not that I am looking for a new job, just curious how my own company showed up there)

Comment: I had a similar thing - I saw an advert for Google Chrome when browsing... with Google Chrome.

Comment: Why is company name "Stealth . Travel." and not "Stealth.travel". I tried to corrected but rejected. So my question to you what is the correct name of your company? Is it "Stealth Travel" or "Stealth . Travel." (as shown in the question) or "Stealth.travel" (as per SO Careers Company Profile)

Comment: Also here the link to my rejected edit: http://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/40036 I don't know how to propose to re-evaluate this

Comment: @HackerKarma oops sorry about that. clicked wrong button x_X

Comment: No problem but it did opened a Pandora's Box. Please, see my new question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260599/substantial-edit-rejected-by-community-%E2%99%A6-ghost-moderator-but

Answer (score 25, accepted):

See, I look at this and think: "Aren't we so smart?  We found you the company you already work for, and you're clearly qualified for that position!".

But really, we're not adding 2+2 because the ads are unaware of your Careers profile and any data within it.  Ads are targeted [based off your Stack Overflow viewing patterns and your location](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2015/01/targeted-jobs-for-stack-overflow/).  We're just not that smart yet.  I do anticipate we'll get smarter, and stop showing you jobs at the company you currently work for.

For now, I see it as a sign that we're doing some pretty decent targeting with the information we have.

Comment: This is still happening, even although we now have "Current position" and "Company name" fields in the Stack Overflow profile. I still see adverts *every day* for my current company, even although the company name in my SO profile is an exact match for that in the advert.