# Substantial edit rejected by Community ♦

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits, community-user, rejected-edits

My recently suggested edit for the [Careers ad asking if I want to work where I already work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260589/careers-ad-asking-if-i-want-to-work-where-i-already-work) question got immediately rejected first by Community ♦ on the following grounds (screenshot):

> [image]

Then, later it got rejected by OP who reviewed the post and made an edit (as shown at the top in the above screenshot).

Here is what my suggested edit looks like:

> [image]

Here is what OP's edit looks like:

> [image]

I found out the following facts:

- Community likes the OP as their edit got approved for lower case "S" and adding "." at the end. If you notice in the OP's edit screenshot above, you will see this "stealth.travel." in the highlighted area.
- OP did not have the word "currently" originally. I added it in my first edit (refer to screenshot #2 above) because the edit was lower than 6 chars.

So, my question is, why did the "Community" aka Ghost moderator rejected my substantial (highlighted in bold below) edit?

Reject:

> I **currently** work for Stealth **.travel**

but approved the OP's tiny change:

> I currently work for **s**tealth.travel **.**

Please share you thoughts on this.

Comment: @Tim Now that I been educated, I can assure you that Community Moderator will not Reject your substantial edit :) Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep...

All my fault :-(

Sorry about that.

I clicked reject and edit instead of accept and edit...

/me runs away in shame....

Comment: +100 for publicly accepting your fault... Thank you.

Comment: Also, this is a classic example of "How to gain a reputation for honesty"

Comment: If +100, where's the bounty?

Answer (score 6):

Actually, community did nothing here.

[image]

> Then, later it got rejected by OP who reviewed the post and made an edit (as shown at the top in the above screenshot).

Other way round.

See the person above. They decided to reject your edit, and then they edited it themselves.

What this means is they thought your edit wasn't that great, and then decided to improve it themselves - this is a feature of the review queue.

However, a user can't just reject an edit on their own - so if they chose to reject *and* edit it, then community provides the second vote.

---

> Why did "Community" reject my edit?

OP can always edit their own post - and also the OP has 2k+ reputation, which means they can edit any post without any review process.

Comment: Tim, Thank you. I did not know that I have to read from TOP

Answer (score 5):

As you can see, the post owner, 'amanaP lanaC A nalP A naM A', rejected your edit and edited it the same time.

The reject will be attributed to Community, where it was really the user mentioned above. The reason is that only a moderator can reject and suggest edit without needing extra votes.

When a 2K+ user or post owner edits the posts and rejects the edit it needs those additional votes for the suggested edit process to end. That's why Community steps in.