# Edit marked as rejected by Community, but actually rolled into someone else's

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, community-user, rejected-edits, attribution

I suggested [this edit](https://diy.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/107383), which was rejected by the Community user due to an edit conflict. However, when I looked at the post, I saw my edit there anyway. Looking at [the revision history](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/186599/revisions), it appears that the asker's edit in revision 2 had its edit summary comment replaced by mine, and my change rolled into it. I find it highly unlikely that the asker would have done both of those things by hand, and much more likely that the site's software caused this somehow. Is this something that the developers just need to fix, or is there something that someone involved didn't do right that caused this? (This is not a duplicate of [Dismiss suggested edits which conflict with full edit instead of auto rejecting them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171469/386992), because in that question, the edits didn't end up going through, but in this one, it did, just attributed to the wrong person.)

Comment: Is the answer here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260599/282094  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184992/why-does-the-community-user-approve-and-reject-edits ? - possibly the OP rejected the edit and sought to improve it, but ended up saving it as-is; thus, actually accepting it. I don't disagree that there's a bug, rather than (possibly incorrectly) using the [attribution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attribution) (and all 5 available tag slots) you should add the [tag:support] tag so a moderator or employee looks behind the scenes (and sees more than we can).

Comment: As the duplicate says, the author loaded up the question before you submitted your suggested edit, and, unaware that you suggested an edit, proceeded to edit it. Due to a bug, though, the system loaded up your suggested edit in the editor they were shown, instead of the original post. They then proceeded to save their edit, and your suggestion was automatically rejected as part of the normal edit conflict logic.